# RequireJS with Multiple modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

I have developed JavaScript based web applications in the past and am now trying to understand RequireJS.
Almost all web apps have pages which would require some common JS and some page specific JS. I want to organize the entire web app using RequireJS.
So my question is can we do the same using RequireJS. If yes, how exactly is the breakup of JS done?
Let's say I have an app.build.js as follows;

```
({
    appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "js",
    dir: "../../appdirectory-build",
    paths: {
      jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.2',
      underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-1.4.4',
      backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-0.9.10',
      templates: '../templates',
      app: 'app'
    },

    shim: {
      underscore: {
        exports: '_'
      },
      backbone: {
        deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
        exports: "Backbone"
      }
    },
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        }
    ]
})
```

Can we have multiple "modules" defined here (like we have the 'main'). Please provide more details. 
Also RequireJS is said to be AMD. So what exactly is asynchronous over here?
Thank you.

Comment: The asynchronous nature of AMD can be seen by looking at what requests RequireJS makes when loading your app. You will see that it will do several requests and will only continue executing the code of a module once all of its dependendencies have been loaded. The actual loading of the dependencies is done asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Over the past few months I've thrown together a few example Mimosa built apps that bundle many modules for use in an app.

This one has nested main modules, 3 built files altogether: https://github.com/dbashford/MimosaNestedMains

It is a rather naive example, but you can see how one could portion out their app into small pieces and build each individually.  To see the r.js run configs that Mimosa builds and uses, run `mimosa build -oD`. That will spew the debug logs to the console and that includes the r.js configs for each file.

Getting started with Mimosa: http://mimosajs.com/started.html